# No able to generate code coverage report with istanbul

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, code-coverage, istanbul

I am running jasmine test framework for an angular2 project. I have chosen istanbul for coverage report but it seems I have done some wrong settings which is why the report is not getting created after running test, Can anybody tell me why.
Below is my karma.conf.js

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('karma-mocha-reporter'),
      require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['@angular/cli']
    },
    mime: {
      'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: config.angularCli && config.angularCli.codeCoverage
              ? ['progress', 'coverage-istanbul', 'karma-remap-istanbul', 'kjhtml', 'mocha']
              : ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'mocha'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    mochaReporter: {
        output: 'noFailures'
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the console error output?

Comment: @ChrisSatchell There is no error in console. I am just not able to find the the coverage report html anywhere in my codebase.

Comment: Are you sure it actually runs through?